# Mongoose MongoDB TTL expiry

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, react-fullstack

I am trying to make a full stack app where the MongoDB BSON document expires after a certain period of time. As you can see below, I put the expiry time at 4 minutes. However, the document gets deleted by  **2:20 minutes**. I have tried testing the expiry time at *2m*, *3m*. They are all expiring at within a span of **2:10-2:45 minutes**. I am not sure why this is happening. What should I do to fix this?

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    note: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    completed:{
        type: Boolean
    },
    createdAt: { type: Date, expires: '4m', default: Date.now }
})

const User = mongoose.model('user', userSchema)

module.exports = User
```

Comment: Did you check the created TTL index?

Comment: I do not know how to create the the TTL index. How should I do that in my code?

Comment: See https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.getIndexes/

Comment: I looked at the document and added index: true. However the results has not changed.